# scanf_s returning Null every time

Tags: c, scanf, c11, tr24731

I am using scanf_s to two different inputs and place them into char arrays. I have attached the code and the output it gives

```
char firstName[30];
char lastName[30];


int main() {

// Input Name
printf("Please input your name: ");
scanf_s("%s %s", firstName, 30, lastName, 30);

printf("%s %s", firstName[30], lastName[30]);
_getch();

return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
Please input your name: Jane Smith
(null) (null)
```

any help to this problem would be great because any scanf_s that I do won't work and its driving me crazy.

Comment: Your call to printf() is bad: Instead of the buffers themselves, you are passing it the values of characters beyond the buffer, which could be anything. You're (un)lucky they happen to be zero.

Comment: Detail: `30` is an `int`.  To comply with Std C, Lib K.,  the size argument should be `size_t`  --> `scanf_s("%s %s", sizeof firstName, sizeof firstName, lastName, sizeof lastName);`  Code has other problems too.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

Your `scanf_s` call is fine. What you need to change is line :

```
printf("%s %s", firstName[30], lastName[30]);
```

Using `printf` like this, you are trying to print the element in position `30` of `firstName` and `lastName` arrays, which not only asks to print a specific position instead of the whole array, but also is out of your arrays' bounds. This invokes [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Replace it with :

```
printf("%s %s", firstName, lastName);
```